# "1-----1--+--1" é um valor inteiro válido no PHP?

Tags: php

Estou testando uma função para filtro de valores do PHP chamada `filter_var()`. E um [dos seus filtros](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), focado em valores tipo `int` parece aceitar qualquer combinação de números, `+` e `-`. Exemplo:

```
filter_var("1teste2", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) // 12
filter_var("1-teste-2", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) // 1--2
filter_var("1--1--+--1", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) // 1--1--+--1
```

Esse é um comportamento normal? A linguagem aceita esse tipo de valor como `int` sem problemas, ou é um *bug* da função de filtro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), sim. Sabe como é, é o PHP, as coisas são feitas para funcionar mais ou menos. E a função faz o que promete mesmo que a expectativa do programador seja outra:

> Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.

A função com esta *flag* não promete transformar a *string* em uma número inteiro válido, ela promete apenas retirar todos os outros caracteres que não sejam dígitos e sinais de menos e mais.

Então a pergunta do título deve ser respondida com um não. Mas a função usada não tem a tarefa de resolver isto. O nome da *flag* dá a entender uma coisa que ela não faz.

Tem exemplos da *flag*][2](http://ideone.com/CWYERY) que provavelmente te atende melhor. Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1Oc9ZI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rqzfflmd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Filter.php).

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: `$var = preg_replace_all('~[^\d+-]~', '', $var);`

Answer (score 10):

Segundo a documentação, esse comportamento é esperado. No caso `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`:

> Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.
>
> Remove todos os caracteres exceto digitos([0-9]), sinais de adição(+) e de subtração(-).