# Qual a diferença entre sanitize e filter em PHP?

Tags: php, segurança, validação, entrada-de-dados

Fazendo uma classe de segurança para *PHP* notei a existência de duas constantes parecidas, como:
`FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` e `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.

O padrão segue em validações de *email*, *string* e outros. Qual a diferença entre essas duas constantes? Quando usar uma ou outra?

O método a seguir estaria 'correto' para uma validação mais segura?

```
public static function int($name)
{
    $_POST[$name] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if(filter_var($_POST[$name], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Há métodos padrões no *PHP*, como `is_int()` e `is_integer()`, mas parece ser menos confiável. (I'm not sure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A diferença entre [`FILTER_SANITIZE_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) e [`FILTER_VALIDATE_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), é que o primeiro tenta 'converter' uma entrada em um formato especifico 'seguro' utilizando regras bem especificas. Essa modificação não garante uma saída válida. Já o segundo verifica se a entrada está dentro do padrão estabelecido (*int*, e-mail, ip etc).

**É importantissímo consultar a documentação (em inglês)** antes de utilizar essas constantes em conjuto com as respectivas funções, pois o seu critério de tratamento pode ser totalmente diferente do fornecido pela linguagem, vide exemplos a seguir.

#### FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT

Tenta converter uma *string* em um número porém a regra utilizada é literalmente frouxa, ela remove todos os caracteres não numéricos (0-9) exceto os símbolos `+`, `-` e `.` que são necessários para representar números negativos ou fracionados. Ou seja existe uma grande chance de um falso positivo. `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` é uma versão menos restritiva que o *cast*:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Digamos que um registro do banco deve ser alterado, mas antes vamos validar a entrada do usuário.

```
$id = '-aaa3';
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //-3

$id2 = '-++';
$id2 = filter_var($id2, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //--+
```

A saída é -3 quando deveria ser retornado falha na conversão.

#### FILTER_VALIDATE_INT

Verifica se a *string* passada é um número válido inteiro (do contrário retorna false, ou seja falha), os símbolos de `+` e menos `-` são permitidos apenas no inicio.

```
$id = '3-';
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); //false

$id = '-3';
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); //-3
```

#### *Code Review*

O código da pergunta pode partir de um premissa errada e passar um resultado incorreto para frente. Por exemplo, a entrada `4@2` não é um inteiro válido, ao aplicar `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` a `@` será removida, tornando agora a entrada em um inteiro válido(`42`). O retorno da função será `true`, porém, esse 42 vai causar algum problema para frente?

Os maiores problemas para validar um inteiro são: não deixar que o PHP faça a conversão da parte numérica da *string* para não gerar falsos positivos e verificar se entrada é composta somente por números (0-9) ou sinais (-+).

`is_integer()` é um alias de `is_int()`, essa função verifica se o tipo da variável é *int*, do contrário retorna `false`. Uma *string* numérica válida retorna `false` e caso alguma conversão seja feita existe o problema de pegar apenas a parte numérica.

O mais indicado e rígido nesse caso é [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php). A função obriga que uma *string* seja passada, e se ela for composta por apenas números (0-9)  retornar `true`.

`ctype_digit()` tem um inconveniente. Caso um inteiro na faixa de -128 a 255 seja passado, será interpretado o código ASCII ou seja retorna `false`. Entretanto existe uma maneira curiosa de converter uma entrada em *string* que é colocar esse valor ou variável entre aspas duplas.

```
$id = 255;
var_dump(ctype_digit("$id")); //true
var_dump(ctype_digit($id)); //false
```

**Relacionado:**

[Por que no PHP a expressão “2 + '6 maçãs'” é igual a 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/91)

[“1-----1--+--1” é um valor inteiro válido no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47093/91)

Comment: Ainda vou adicionar mais alguma coisa.

Comment: Ótimo, só uma dúvida, em relação ao método que citei na pergunta, é uma maneira certa de validar entradas?

Comment: @lvcs to editando aos poucos, depende um pouco da situação, se for p saber se o número é inteiro, não me parece uma boa opção (claro depende da rigidez q vc precisa). O problema que vejo é a função pega a parte numérica(se existir) da entrada, filtra mais ou menos de forma adequada e passa p frente ex 4@5, remove a @ vira 45 inteiro válido porém o q acontece se eu passar ele p frente, vai acontecer o resultado esperado? Depois detalho e adiciono isso na resposta.

Comment: Ah sim, consegui entender, por um lado realmente não é uma melhor opção.