# Estou validando duas vezes?

Tags: php, validação, int

Olá, eu possuo um Select em um formulário tendo como valores apenas números inteiros.

Ao receber essas informações no PHP, eu faço as seguintes validações:

[image: Validação]

Por já estar usando `(int)` na linha 297 e na linha 302, a minha primeira validação (na linha 292, com o `!is_numeric`) é redundante?

Na linha 292 eu verifico se é um número, na linha 297 se não é "0" (o que indicaria que é a primeira opção do select "Selecione...", ou seja, o usuário enviou o form sem selecionar nenhuma opção) e na linha 302 eu verifico se a opção selecionada realmente existe no DB (e que não foi manualmente alterada pelo "Inspecionar Elemento") e que não é "99", o que equivale a opção "Outros", do select.

Ou seja, como estou usando o (int), eu realmente preciso da linha 292? Ou eu preciso fazer esse double-check?

Obrigado.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre sanitize e filter em php?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139586/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é redundante.

Poderia aplicar o cast uma única vez. O nome disso é sanitização (sanitize).

Após sanitizar, faça a filtragem e validação.

Exemplo

```
$var = (int)$var; // Faz o cast para numérico inteiro

// verifica se é vazio ou igual a zero.
// o motivo é que o casting acima remove tudo que não for numérico.
if (empty($var || $var == 0)) {
    // mensagem de erro
}
```

No outro trecho do `checkcategoryid` e `!= 99`, inverta a ordem verificando primeiro se é 99 pois assim evitará processo desnecessário caso o número for 99.

<sub>nota: Essa resposta é baseada somente no trecho de código que postou, tal como as explicações na pergunta.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do CheckCategoryId, nem tinha passado pela minha cabeça.