# Como validar determinados valores em PHP se (quase?) todos são recebidos do formulário como string?

Tags: php, formulário

Não sei se são todos valores, mas em geral, o PHP recebe tudo como *string* quando vem de um formulário. Digamos que eu queira validar a idade:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <button type="submit">Manda</button>
</form>
```

E em `test.php`:

```
if(!is_int($_POST['age'])){
    echo 'não é integer';
    var_dump($_POST['age']);
}
```

Pode ver que utilizando `var_dump()` eu recebo como string as informações de "*age*" e entra no `if`, mesmo eu digitando `14` no formulário, por exemplo. Então, como validar determinados valores em PHP se (quase?) todos são recebidos do formulário como *string*?

Exemplos serão bem-vindos.

Comment: [Qual a diferença entre sanitize e filter em php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139586/91)

Answer (score 0):

Mas oq ue gostaria de fazer exatamente? PHP é meio simplista nesta parte. se vc receber uma variável que só tenha números e somar com outra que só tenha números ele irá calcular normalmente como se fosse integer
por exemplo

```
if($_POST['age'] >= 18){ echo "pessoa é maior de idade"; }
```

Comment: como é campo post vc precisa verificar se na varivel contém algo além de números